# cloud data prep - Data Service Unknown Error when importing data from Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to import data from Big Query into Cloud Dataprep but I receive the following error message : "CONNEXION ERROR - Data Service unknown error"
I have also this message in the console : "java.lang.NullPointerException"
Any thoughts on this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this question belongs here, it would more helpful in Stackoverflow.

This happens when there is a BQ table without a schema in the dataset.

Make sure each table in the dataset has a schema defined and you should be good to go.

You can create a table with a [simple schema definition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_an_empty_table_with_a_schema_definition) that will be updated by dataprep.